# USB Mass Storage recognized, but SCSI block-device not showing up

Tags: storage, usb, scsi, block-device

The block-device of a USB mass storage does not show up in `Ubuntu 16.04`, while I positively can see it in `Ubuntu 14.04`. Question: How can I make it show up in `Ubuntu 16.04`?

NOTES:

1. Both machines are virtual on the same hardware, so it is not cabling, wiring, power, connection, blah blah... Virtualization of the `USB` is identical and I have triple-checked it is not the problem.
2. In fact... the USB layer **is** properly detected **both** in `Ubuntu 14.04` and `Ubuntu 16.04` (see the logs below).
3. The block device `/dev/sdb` shows up in `Ubuntu 14.04` (as expected), but does not show up in `Ubuntu 16.04` (topic of this question).
4. The problem **seems** to be located in something named `usb-storage` which in the `Ubuntu 14.04` is bridging the `USB` into the `SCSI` but seems to be missing in my installation of the `Ubuntu 16.04`.

## Context

I have two Vagrant/VirtualBox machines. One with `Ubuntu 14.04` and the other with `Ubuntu 16.04`. In the host, I have a `JMicron`-based dock with a 1T HD plugged in (chip product `JMS56x`).

The drive is not formatted and has no partitions, I plan to use the raw-block device in a pool fo `ZFS`.

I want to do the usage of the `ZFS` from inside `Ubuntu 16.04`.

### In Ubuntu 14.04

I use the vagrant image `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"` and I already have `usbutils` installed:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home/vagrant# apt list --installed | grep usb

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

libusb-0.1-4/trusty,now 2:0.1.12-23.3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libusb-1.0-0/trusty,now 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
usbutils/trusty,now 1:007-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

I tell VirtualBox to connect the `JMicron` and I successfully get the block-device as a `SCSI` disk.

#### Before connecting

Before connecting the disk, I can see `sda` and its unique partition `sda1`:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home/vagrant# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Nov 26 13:06 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Nov 26 13:06 /dev/sda1
```

#### After connecting

After connecting, I can see both `sda` and `sdb` (in this case, `sdb` with no partitions, as expected):

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home/vagrant# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 Nov 26 13:06 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 Nov 26 13:06 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Nov 26 16:56 /dev/sdb
```

`fdisk` gives coherent results with the `/dev/sd*` listings.

So `Ubuntu 14.04` behaves exactly as expected, as the the block device `/dev/sdb` shows up.

### In Ubuntu 16.04

I use the vagrant image `config.vm.box = "gbarbieru/xenial"` and I don't have the `usbutils` installed. I install them via `apt install usbutils` and after that I get:

```
root@vagrant:/home/vagrant# apt list --installed | grep usb

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libusb-0.1-4/xenial,now 2:0.1.12-28 amd64 [installed]
libusb-1.0-0/xenial,now 2:1.0.20-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
usbutils/xenial,now 1:007-4 amd64 [installed]
```

I tell VirtualBox to connect the `JMicron` and I **do not get any extra block device** and this is the main problem.

#### Before connecting

Before connecting the disk, I can see `sda` and its several partitions `sda1`, `sda2` and `sda5`:

```
root@vagrant:/home/vagrant# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda5
```

#### After connecting

After connecting, I **cannot see** in `Ubuntu 16.04` any `sdb` as I could see with the `Ubuntu 14.04`:

```
root@vagrant:/home/vagrant# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Nov 26 10:55 /dev/sda5
```

`fdisk` gives coherent results with the `/dev/sd*` listings.

So `Ubuntu 16.04` does not behave as expected because the block device `/dev/sdb` does not show up. Nevertheless, the low-level USB device **is** in fact properly detected. See the logs:

### Traces and logs

In `Ubuntu 14.04` I get following traces in `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` when connecting:

```
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.532808] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.553057] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=9561
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.553060] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.553062] usb 1-1: Product: JMS56x Series
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.553064] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.553065] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.557954] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov 26 16:14:34 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11313.557991] scsi2 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.557915] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD10 EAVS-00D7B1      0105 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.558304] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.564883] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.566221] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.566225] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.571284] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.572366] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.579291] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Nov 26 16:14:35 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11314.579651] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Nov 26 16:14:36 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11315.056332]  sdb: unknown partition table
Nov 26 16:14:36 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11315.066919] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Nov 26 16:14:36 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11315.067273] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Nov 26 16:14:36 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [11315.070669] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Instead, in `Ubuntu 16.04` I get those traces in `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` when connecting the device:

```
Nov 26 11:14:59 vagrant kernel: [ 1178.761744] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Nov 26 11:14:59 vagrant kernel: [ 1179.088626] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=9561
Nov 26 11:14:59 vagrant kernel: [ 1179.088632] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Nov 26 11:14:59 vagrant kernel: [ 1179.088636] usb 1-1: Product: JMS56x Series
Nov 26 11:14:59 vagrant kernel: [ 1179.088638] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
Nov 26 11:14:59 vagrant kernel: [ 1179.088641] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
```

The first missing line is:

```
usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

So comparing both logs, it seems that "something named `usb-storage`" is not present. Probably the `usb-storage` thing is the bridge to the `SCSI`.

## Questions

1. Is `usb-storage` still the way to go in 2016? Or shoud I use another bridge?
2. How do I get the `usb-storage` thing active in the `Ubuntu 16.04` so it continues the process, exposes the storage to the `SCSI` and I get the `/dev/sdb` block device listed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `modprobe usb-storage` or `modprobe usb_storage` before connecting the USB disk. Does it change anything?

Comment: I start to see... usb_storage is a kernel module... Thanks for the tip. It is present in the `14.04` but it is not present in the `16.04` that I am using. `ls -l /lib/modules/*/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/` displays `usb-storage.ko` in the `14.04` but is missing in the `16.04`. Is it possible to install kernel modules **without** recompiling (for example from apt-get or so?) - Or I necessarily **have** to compile?

Comment: Can you post the output of `zgrep -i usb /proc/config.gz` (or any other kernel config file) ?

Comment: I don't have `/proc/config.gz` but I have `/boot/config*`. I have dumped them in this `gist`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/29c13e97165d955ca07d6f983132f228 - see snippet1 & snippet2 for the `ubuntu/trusty64` and `gbarbieru/xenial` vagrant boxes respectively. Seems they both have `CONFIG_USB_STORAGE=m`, instead in the `/lib/modules/*` directory I can't see the `.../kernel/drivers/usb/*` in the xenial, only in the trusty - snippets 3 and 4 of the same gist. So... may I dynamically add the "module" in the filesystem at `/lib/modules/*` and have my kernel load the `*.ko` without recompiling?

Comment: I just checked on a Ubuntu 16.04.01 and I can confirm that `usb-storage.ko` *is present* under `/lib/modules/<version>/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/`. If you have no modules, try installing a newer/different kernel via `apt-get`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use just generic kernel without usb-storage module.
To have usb storage working just install *linux-image-extra* package

E.g. on ubuntu 16.04:

```
apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) -y
```

And then load usb-storage module or disconnect/connect your device

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# modprobe usb-storage
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# dmesg | tail
[  698.649461] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  698.650107] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  699.667145] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB DISK 2.0     PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  699.668667] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  699.679897] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 30289920 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.4 GiB)
[  699.687947] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  699.687951] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
[  699.695974] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  699.753448]  sdc: sdc1
[  699.798466] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```